# Map dynamic nested Json object to hashmap and store keys and values into two string variable with comma separated

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I need to map dynamimc json nested object into hashmap I could come up with solution but I couldn't get expected output.

Here is code

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new Gson().fromJson(dynamicJson, HashMap.class);

        String keys = map.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        String values = map.values().stream().map(obj -> String.valueOf(obj)).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        System.out.println("Keys: " + keys);
        System.out.println("Values: " + values);
```

Sample Json

```
{
    "name": "Notification 2", 
    "message": "Facebook",
    "tags":[
        {
        "city" : "Matara",
        "village" : "Mirissa"
        }      
          ]
}
```

Actual output :

> name, message, tags Notification 2, Facebook, [{city=Matara,
> village=Mirissa}]

Expected output

> name, message, tags/city, tag/village

> Notification 2, Facebook, Matara, Mirissa

Answer (score 0):

In above logic you are not processing sub elements, check below code
HashMap<String, Object> map = new Gson().fromJson(dynamicJson, HashMap.class);

```
Map<String, String> keyValueMap = new HashMap<>();

map.forEach((key, value) -> {
  if (value instanceof List) {
    ((List)value).stream().forEach(obj -> { // processing sub elements 
      if (obj instanceof Map) {
        ((Map)obj).forEach((k,v) -> {
          keyValueMap.put(key+"/"+k, v.toString());
        });
      }
    });
  } else { // direct value, no subelement
    keyValueMap.put(key, value.toString());
  }
});
```

The above logic will work for only elements which are inside `List`, so you need modify above logic little more generic based on your input json structure.
Below logic is to print the data which can be optimzed , i have written below logic so that it will be easy to understand

```
keyValueMap.forEach((k, v) -> { 
   System.out.print(k+ ",");
});
System.out.println();
    
keyValueMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
    System.out.print(v+ ",");
});
```

it will give out put as below

```
name,tags/city,message,tags/village,
Notification 2,Matara,Facebook,Mirissa,
```

Thanks
Prasad